# Query in django orm to get all users in a list from django authentication group returns empty list

Tags: python, django, orm

In my code below, the list is empty, it does not contain user name in list.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

def first(request):
    from django.contrib.auth import models

    groups = Group.objects.all()

# Create an empty list to store users
    all_users = []

# Iterate through the groups and get users for each grou
    for group in groups:
        users = group.user_set.all()
        all_users.extend(users)

    print(all_users)    
   
     
    return render(request,'first.html')
```

I expected to get users details but got an empty list. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Exactly why do you access the users through the `Group`s?

Answer (score 0):

You here obtain the `User`s that belong to *at least* one `Group`, but likely you did not assign any of the users to (any) groups.

You can obtain all the users with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def first(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'first.html', {'users': users})
```